# mysql increment weight field on insert

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following columns

```
id
parent_id
title
description
weight
```

every row belongs to a parent. every row has a weight that determines its order on the parent page.
Every time a new row is added I want the weight of that new row to be equal to the largest weight for that parent id +1.

Is there a way to do it within the insert query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i'm not sure it will work as i don't have a sql server on hand. But i beleve i have done something like this before.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, parent_id, title, description, weight) 
VALUES (2,1,'title', 'description', 1+(SELECT MAX(weight) FROM table))
```

Replace table with your table name and the values with the ones you need, ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

This should works

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id,parent_id,title,description,weight)
VALUES (idValue,parentValue,idValue,titleValue,descriptionValue,
        (SELECT MAX(weight) FROM myTable WHERE parent = parentValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

if 
parent_id=1 and
id=111

```
INSERT INTO table (id, parent_id, title, description, weight) 
VALUES (111,1,'title', 'description', (SELECT MAX(weight) FROM table WHERE parent_id=1) + 1)
```